# Google Places Web API keyword

Tags: google-places-api

In Google's Places Web API you have the option of adding one or more keywords. Does anyone know how much every keyword counts?
Ex: if I have 2 keywords : hamburger and pizza, how will it provide the places. Can I set a weight for each one, so if it finds a place that contains the keyword with the greater weight, it will return that place, and if it finds a place that contains only the word with the smaller weight it will not be returned?

Comment: Typically Google doesn't share their algorithms, I think we cannot provide a precise answer for this question.